# Distinguish between lm object and rlm object

Tags: r, regression, lm

I am trying to distinguish between a LM object and a RLM (robust LM from MASS) because depending on which type of regression is I want to perform one thing or another. So fitList can be either a lm or a rlm model, being all the elements of the list the same type.

*fitList* as a list of several normal linear models:

```
fitList[[1]]$call
Output: lm(formula = frmla, data = xList[[i]])
```

And in this second case, *fitList* as a list of several robust linear models:

```
fitList[[1]][1]$call
Output: rlm(formula = frmla, data = xList[[i]], method = "MM")
```

As you see, the way to obtain the formula used in both models is different. I'd like a method that distinguishes between both and tells me if the list is a list of linear models or a list of robust linear models. After many attempts I haven't manage to get a way to obtain which one it is.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: You want to get the class of the model, not the `call` attribute of the model.  Try `class(fittry[[1]])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reproducible example:

```
library(MASS)
fitlm <- lm(Height ~., trees)
fitrlm <- rlm(Height ~., trees)
class(fitlm)[1]
class(fitrlm)[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

**1) inherits** This will return a logical indicating whether an object, `fm`, is of `"rlm"` class returning `TRUE` if so and `FALSE` otherwise:

```
inherits(fm, "rlm")
```

For example,

```
if (inherits(fm, "rlm")) {
     # process rlm
} else {
     # process lm
}
```

If `L` is a list of such models then this processes them all:

```
f <- function(fm) {
   # if statement above
}
lapply(L, f)
```

or to get a logical vector indicating which ones are `"rlm"` models:

```
sapply(L, inherits, "rlm")
```

**2) S3 Dispatch**  Another approach is to define a `process` generic and then define a method to handle each class.  In this example we just return the name of the class but in your application you would replace that with all the processing to handle an object of that class.

```
process <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("process")
process.rlm <- function(x, ...) "rlm"
process.lm <- function(x, ...) "lm"
process.default <- function(x, ...) "error"

lapply(L, process)
```